# Can C++ class instances on the stack be captured by Objective-C blocks?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++, objective-c-blocks

I'm seeing some strange behavior when trying to capture an instance of a C++ class on the stack in an Objective-C block.  Consider the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test
{
  Test() : flag(0) { printf("%p default constructor\n", this); }
  Test(const Test& other) : flag(0) { printf("%p copy constructor\n", this); }
  ~Test() { flag = 1; printf("%p destructor\n", this); }

  int flag;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  Test test;
  void (^blk)(void) = ^(void)
    {
      printf("flag=%d (test=%p)\n", test.flag, &test);
    };
  printf("about to call blk\n");
  blk();

  [pool release];

  return 0;
}
```

One would expect that when the local variable `test` gets captured by the block `blk`, it has a consistent state.  However, that is not the case.  The output of this code is the following:

```
0x7fff5fbff650 default constructor
0x7fff5fbff630 copy constructor
about to call blk
0x7fff5fbff5d0 copy constructor
0x7fff5fbff5d0 destructor
flag=1 (test=0x7fff5fbff5d0)
0x7fff5fbff630 destructor
0x7fff5fbff650 destructor
```

So the local `Test` instance that the block sees has had its destructor called!  Anything you do with it is undefined behavior, which would very likely lead to a crash (e.g. if the destructor deleted a pointer without setting it to NULL).

Are C++ class instance variables supported by Objective-C blocks?  The [Block Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) section "C++ Objects" seems to indicate that they are, but they clearly aren't working here.  Is this a bug in the compiler/runtime?  This was tested on GCC 4.2.1, Apple build 5666, on Mac OS X v10.6.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say its a bug in GCC.

When I try it with GCC, I get:

```
0x7fff5fbff5d0 default constructor
0x7fff5fbff5c0 copy constructor
about to call blk
0x7fff5fbff570 copy constructor
0x7fff5fbff570 destructor
flag=1 (test=0x7fff5fbff570)
0x7fff5fbff5c0 destructor
0x7fff5fbff5d0 destructor
```

But using LLVM 2.0:

```
0x7fff5fbff610 default constructor
0x7fff5fbff600 copy constructor
about to call blk
flag=0 (test=0x7fff5fbff600)
0x7fff5fbff600 destructor
0x7fff5fbff610 destructor
```

The latter follows my interpretation of the documentation for blocks (and is the only version that isn't flagrantly broken).

Comment: Sweet - you're right :-) I ran into BAD_ACCESS exceptions when accessing the elements of a std::map declared outside the block. The [BlockLanguageSpec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt) states, that "Stack-local objects are copied into a Block via a copy const constructor.", so it should work and therefore is a bug. Switching to LLVM 3.0 solved the issue.